PyCharm Debugger Failing with Timeout Error - Works Fine with ‘Run’ Command
I am currently using PyCharm 2023.3.5 (Professional Edition) and experiencing an issue where the debugger fails to work. When running the program normally without debugging, everything works fine. However, when I try to debug, the following error occurs:
“Error running 'test' Timeout expired: 30000 MILLISECONDS”


I’m not sure how to resolve this issue. Here are some details and steps I’ve already checked:

SSH and Deployment Settings:

My SSH configuration and deployment settings appear to be correct.

Tools > SSH Configurations > Test Connection: Successfully connected!


Python Interpreter:

There doesn’t seem to be an issue with the Python interpreter. I’m using the interpreter located on the same host as specified in my SSH configuration, and the path mappings are correctly set.

Project > Python Interpreter: No issues detected.


Inconsistent Behavior:

What’s confusing is that if I create a new project and connect it to the same interpreter with a simple file, the debugger works just fine. However, when I copy the problematic file into this new project and attempt to debug, the debugger stops working again.
Does anyone know what might be causing this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
